# Verifying Workflow Manager Client Installation

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, workflow-manager

This is a similar question to [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/265874/webflow-manager-client-usage-and-how-to-verify-the-installation) but I was asked to post a new question instead of posting on that one. So, my question is regarding Workflow Manager Client. I just installed the WFM server component on the app server in my SP farm (the farm is a small farm with one WFE, one app server and one DB backend).

As per the instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/governance/install-and-configure-workflow-for-sharepoint-server), it says for my scenario (installing WFM on a server in the SP farm and using HTTPS), I was supposed to:

- Install WFM
- Run the Register-SPWorkflowService cmdlet to pair the WFM farm with the SP farm
- Install the WFM Client on the remaining SP farm servers

...in that order. So that is exactly what I did. Everything went smoothly with both the WFM server and client installations. But after installing the client, when I run the following cmdlets on the WFM server:

```
Get-WFFarm
Get-WFFarmStatus
```

...it only shows the WFM server (SP app server) as the only machine in the farm (the output of `Get-WFFarmStatus` shows it as both the frontend and backend). But there is no mention in the output of either cmdlet about the WFE, which is running the WFM Client.

So, I am trying to find out how I can verify that the client is properly joined to the WFM farm. And I'm also wondering if the instructions at the MS link above are incorrect, because many other things I'm reading now are saying to run the `Register-SPWorkflowService` cmdlet *after* installing the WFM client on all SP servers, which contradicts the info in the MS article. The article (which is recent - 2018) only says to do things in that order if installing WFM on a server *outside* the SP farm, which was not my scenario. But if I did do things in the wrong order - should I run the cmdlet again (now that the client is installed)? Is there any harm in doing so?

I have done a lot of Googling on this issue and I have not been able to find any info at all on how to validate a Workflow Manager Client installation/how to confirm that a WFM client is properly joined to the WFM farm and communicating w/ the WFM server properly. The Workflow Service App Proxy says it is running and when I go to its details, it says "Workflow is connected". But again, this gives me no info on the client.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is correct behavior. `Get-WFFarm` etc (and the SB cmdlets) will report the Workflow Manager *servers*. You only have 1.

To test, use SharePoint Designer 2013 and create a SharePoint 2013 workflow.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply but I just got a chance to create and test a SharePoint 2013 workflow, and it appears that everything is working properly (able to create and publish the workflow via SPD and the workflow is able to run successfully). And the bit about why the client doesn't show up in the command output makes sense as well. Thanks for the help!